# Can't move ArmatureAction in the timeline!

Tags: animation, armature

I apologize for the quick questions, but I encountered a problem after I got out of that last one just now..

So, I successfully used "Append" to bring in the model and animation from the separate Blender project.

Now, I need to duplicate the little character and "offset" the animation by a few seconds.

In order to do that, I copy+pasted the "Armature" (as can be seen on the top right), and voila! Two characters doing the same motion in-sync.
[image: Pic1]
But now, when I go into the Playback bar on the bottom, and drag-select every keyframe to move it a few seconds later, the keyframes at "Armatureaction" does NOT get moved!
[image: Pic2]
I open up the tab to find that there's only a "Head" section, whose movements DID in fact get moved (and can be seen moving by itself a few seconds later, the way I want it), but there's no other body part. (Pic 3)
[image: Pic3]

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why does the head move but no other part moves?

Again, I apologize for my childish questions, but I can't even start to figure out how I can fix this problem.

Thank you all! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Disable the [options to only show selected keyframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnuRZ.png) or go into pose mode and select all bones.

Comment: @Leander ALWAYS! As SOON as I solve the problem, someone kindly steps in and tells me what to do... :( I can't thank you enough for the help, I really thank you for it!